Trying to set individual CPU frequencies in Linux
On my quad core processor, the third core is defective. In Linux, either I need to lock the whole processor frequency to 3 GHz, or set the third core offline to not crash.
I am trying to find a way to use the third core at lower frequency, while running others at max. Access to Turbo Ratio Limits is locked by the firmware, and so are voltage controls, which could solve the problem.
So if changing the individual frequencies is not possible at hardware level, then I want to do it through software.
Having asynchronous clock speed across all cores isn't something different. Different frequency is always being run on different cores based on the current power profile. So how can I make it so that my third core (CPUs 2 and 6) has a lower max frequency than others?
I have already trying fiddling a lot with like cpupower, cpufreq, intel_pstate, acpi-freq, and the kernel files. I have come to the conclusion that on my machine with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, the userspace governor doesn't load with intel_pstate on, and loads but has no effect when running with intel_pstate disabled, and no matter where I fiddle with the kernel files, and specify what in them, I am not able to set a different clock speed to different cores.
Please, I really need help. I have been trying to fix this from months now.

Can you list more specifics regarding what "fiddling" you've done in cpupower/cpufreq/etc?

@music2myear I guess starting from square 1 with your ideas would be better. I have stuff tried in jumbled up order, but if you want to hear then, I have stuff tried like setting the frequency per core using cpupower/cpufreq, tried to active userspace governer with and without intel_pstate and with pstate passive and active and with hwp on/off. Tried to set the speed in kernel files like scaling_set_speed, scaling_max_frequency, and you know, stuff like that. Just you give a try and start from square one.
